# What is $\frac{(-2)^{x}}{2^{x-1}}$

Tags: exponential-function

The title says it all:

$$\frac{(-2)^{x}}{2^{x-1}}$$

How is this computed?  I'm reviewing the finer points of exponents so a thorough explanation would be most appreciated!

Comment: Defining $a^x$ when $a<0$ and $x$ is not an integer is a tricky matter, because of the issues with complex numbers. For example $(-2)^\pi$ is multi-valued and there is no "canonical" choice of a value for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laws of exponents say that $(ab)^x=a^xb^x$, and $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$. Therefore $$\frac{(-2)^x}{2^{x+1}}=\frac{(-1)^x2^x}{2\cdot 2^x}=\frac{(-1)^x}{2}.$$
This expression is a real number if $x$ is an integer. If $x$ is an even integer, it is equal to $1/2$. If $x$ is an odd integer, then it is equal to $-1/2$.

Comment: Massive edit!  It should be a negative sign in the denominator!  My apologies!

Comment: Its only a minor edit. You should be able to apply similar thinking to answer the question with a plus replacing the minus sign.

Comment: Think I got it though, it just takes the negative sign and hops up in the numerator.

Comment: Correct. I'd suggest rolling back your question to your original so anyone looking at this in the future isn't confused.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $(-2)^x$ can be written as $((-1)(2))^x = (-1)^x(2)^x$.

Comment: I got that, it's mostly that denominator that's causing me trouble.  Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @DonShrinkle The $2^x$ here cancels with the $2^{x-1}$ in the denominator, producing $2$.

Comment: so now we only have to calculate $2(-1)^x$, the definitions I know for this involve complex numbers.